# Cómo mostrar GIT BASH con clic derecho en cualquier directorio de windows

Tags: git, github, git-bash

Cómo mostrar GIT BASH con clic derecho en cualqueir directorio de windows:
(Tengo la opción en el menú>Inicio de Windows 10, pero no me sale cuando hago clic con el botón derecho en cualquier directorio. ¿Cómo se activa para visualizarlo de esa manera?

[image: co]

Gracias.

Comment: Seleccionaste la opción ["Windows Explorer integration"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTQWk.jpg) durante la instalación?

Comment: no he visto esa opción. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paso 1: Crea un nuevo Documento de texto llamado OpenGitBash.reg

Paso 2: Click derecho y edita el fichero

Paso 3: Copia y pega el siguiente código

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
; Open files
; Default Git-Bash Location C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open Git Bash]
@="Open Git Bash"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open Git Bash\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe\" \"--cd=%1\""

; This will make it appear when you right click ON a folder
; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\bash]
@="Open Git Bash"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe"


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\bash\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe\" \"--cd=%1\""

; This will make it appear when you right click INSIDE a folder
; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\bash]
@="Open Git Bash"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\bash\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe\" \"--cd=%v.\""
```

Paso 4: Doble click en el fichero (debes tener permiso de administrador)

Otra solución es volver a instalar Git y marcar la opcion "Windows Explorer Integration"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: yo eh instalado la forma portable no la setup entonces al querer abrir un carpeta no me figura el git bash o git cmd , cual seria la solución.
muchas gracias